# ajax controls are not working in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I am trying to put a calender extender in my aspx page but it is not working and showing no error, but when i try to do this at another project so its working.
what is the problem with my current page ? plz help me.
my code is .......

below is my code

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Add Tax.aspx.cs" Inherits="HMS.Add_Tax" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
<tr>
        <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager> 
        <td class="auto-style2">Applies From</td>
        <td class="auto-style10">                 
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtdate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>                
            <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtdate" PopupButtonID="txtdate" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" Enabled="true">
            </asp:CalendarExtender>
        </td>
```

Comment: open your browser tools and check for javascript errors

Comment: you might need to refference jquery.ajax-unobtrusive.js